# Webdriver Backed Selenium, missing confirmation dialog

Tags: java, selenium, junit, webdriver, confirmation

I have a problem related to some strange behavior when trying to test confirmation popups using Webdriver Backed Selenium in JUnit.

I have a following chunk of code in my test case:

```
assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.xpath("//input[@title='Delete Site']")));
selenium().click("//input[@title='Delete Site']");
//assertTrue(selenium().isConfirmationPresent());
//assertEquals(selenium().getConfirmation(), "Are you sure want to delete this item?");
selenium().waitForPageToLoad("30000");
```

The above lines refer to the following element:

```
<input onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete this item?');" value="Delete Site" type="image" title="Delete Site" src="/workthru-web/resources/images/delete.png" class="image" alt="Delete Site">
```

However, the test fails on the commented lines. When I do the same manually, a prompt appears as expected. Is it possible that popup windows are disabled when running WebDriver? I create my driver using `new FirefoxDriver()`, no extra params present. Do I need extra configuration? Or am I missing something else here?

Comment: What does "test fails" mean? Any exception thrown? The dialog [should not appear](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp#handling-browser-popup-windows), that's correct. However, it should return `true` by default and not fail the test.

Comment: Also, what is the `selenium()` method call? Are you creating a fresh `WebDriverBackedSelenium` instance every time?

Comment: By "test fails" I meant that the the first assertion commented out fails. Note that if I leave the comments as they are, I never consume the confirmation prompt, so Selenium should fail at the next command. Clearly that does not happen. I am aware that the dialog should not appear.

Comment: `selenium()` is just a property getter for a Selenium instance, it does not create a new Selenium instance every time.

Comment: And if you leave the assertion commented and uncomment only second one, does that work? If not, try waiting for the condition to become `true` for a few seconds, maybe the confirm() doesn't show itself right away and is slower than the Selenium call.

Comment: If I leave the first assertion commented, I get the following exception: `com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: There were no confirmations`. I also tried waiting for 5 sec, I suppose that's more than enough for a prompt to load.

Comment: So, I just tried your scenario (http://pastebin.com/Baj58yR0 on http://pastebin.com/HBXux7cX) and it works well, everything passes. Firefox 17, Selenium 2.29.0, Windows XP.

Comment: Funny thing is, your test worked for me, too. Upgraded to 2.29, still nothing. Many thanks for your help, though. For now, I spent too much time trying to figure it out, if I ever learn what the problem is, I'll post it here.

Comment: Three additional ideas before I give up. Did you try in another browser? Also, make sure that the right element is being clicked at all. Selenium is a mysterious beast sometimes. Add a specific effect to the click on the element to see whether it's really being clicked. If yes, try [`fireEvent("//input[@title='Delete Site']", "click");`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#fireEvent%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I tried switching to HtmlUnit, but I keep getting JavascriptException when trying to create the driver. Using fireEvent does trigger a confirmation popup, but I can actually see it, and after a while, a `com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Modal dialog present` is thrown. Another funny thing: when I record my test case using the Selenium IDE, an assertConfirmation command gets recorded, but the test case fails on playback.

Comment: Wow. Mindboggling. I'd either skip this, or try WebDriver. If you ever solve it, please share.